# react-jsonschema-form generate with data

Tags: javascript, jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

I m using **react-jsonschema-form** generator with **NJsonSchema**. After submit form i record json output and i want to use form for edit with submitted data any time.
But i cannot find a way create the form with submitted data before.
After try some json schema updates, I realize, the value keys in json not for filling inputs.

```
 "Age": {
          "value": "34",
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int32"
        }
```

here is react render code :

```
 render((
  <Form schema={schemaTest}
        uiSchema={uiSchema}
        onChange={log("changed")}
        onSubmit={log("submitted")}
        onError={log("errors")} />
), document.getElementById("app"));
```

is there any way filling inputs with json data, while form creating.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it. react-jsonschema-form has formData prop.
https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-reference/form-props/#formdata

Often you'll want to prefill a form with existing data; this is done by passing a formData prop object matching the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the values in states. Then try to put those states to each fields "default" properties.

Eg: "Age": {
"value": "34",
"type": "integer",
"format": "int32",
"default":this.state.formdata.age
}